# Android: Turning a Broadcast receiver into a service

Tags: android, service

Thanks to a good bit of help I got from someone in my last question I am further ahead then before. Now I need to figure out how make this broadcast into a service. Or do I need to make a 3rd file and make a service out of that class?

Any help would be cool!

Answer (score 0):

create a class which extends Service.

```
public class myService extends Service{
```

and use the Application Context object passed to your BroadcastReceiver to start the service.

```
context.startService(intent);
```

If you need to carry data over from your Intent object put a set of extras into the Intent object you create when you call

```
sendBroadcast(Intent intent);
```

Comment: `public class myService extends Service {

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
  return null;
 }


}` <--- this is what I got so far!